# samlspbundle integration with fosuserbundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I try to integrate the bundle samlspbundle on a project running with fosuserbundle.

I actually received information from my idp which send me the saml with the email address of the user.

What i'm trying to do is load the user from my table fosuser and then authenticate it.

this is the method i am in my model SamlToUser :

```
private function loadUserByTargetedID($targetedID)
{
    $repository = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager()->getRepository('MCCAppBDDBundle:User');

    $user = $repository->findOneBy(
        array('email' => $targetedID)
    );

    if ($user) {
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('homepage');
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

        $this->container->get('fos_user.security.login_manager')->loginUser(
            $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name'),
            $user,
            null
        );

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        return $user;
    }

    throw new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException();
}
```

After that i have this error : PHP Warning:  session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent

I'm not sure is the right thing to do.

If you need other detail, i can give you.

Thanks to help.

Comment: where you able to solve this??